# Cannot re-iterate a pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-programming, traversal

I have a pointer array of items that I read in from a file. These items are `typedef structs`.

My array is resizable as the file contains a lot of items.

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%X %[^\n]", &code, string) != EOF) {
    if (list->length >= list->capacity) {
        list->capacity *= 2;
        list->items = (Item**)realloc(list->items,
            list->capacity * sizeof(Item*));
    }
    item.code = code;
    strcpy(item.string, string);
    list->items[list->length++] = &item;
}
```

Assume `list` and `item` are declared already. Space is malloced for list.

`static List * list;` &
`Item item = { 0, { 0 } };`

are declared and initialized earlier in the code. `list` is a global variable by necessity.

If I try to iterate this completed list by attempting to get the first value for instance:

```
printf("line %d: %X\t%-89s\n", 1, list->items[0]->code, list->items[0]->string);
```

I will get the last element in the file from this. However if I were to include this `printf` in the aforementioned while loop, I will get desired console output (when the index is `list->length`).

Why would I be experiencing this type of behavior? Is there something I am forgetting about traversing pointers?

Comment: Never `realloc` directly into the target pointer - always use a temp and check for NULL

Comment: You're assigning the pointer to the **same** item all the time! Aren't you supposed to `malloc` a *new* `Item` too for every iteration. If you wear red, green and yellow shirt in succession there aren't 3 people with colour rainbow, there is just you wearing a yellow shirt.

Comment: You need to show how `List` and `Item` are declared. It seems you are messing up between `Item` and `Item*`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I am sorry but your analogy does not make sense. I get what you are saying with the repeating thing though.

Comment: @compolo but it absolutely does! You do not have n distinct `Item` objects. Just one, and `n` pointers pointing to **that one item**.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you use `item` as an automatic `Item` object and therefore fills the `list->items` array with pointers to the same `Item` object.

You probably want a new `Item` in each loop. Like:

```
Item* newItem;
while (fscanf(fp, "%X %[^\n]", &code, string) != EOF) {
    newItem = malloc(sizeof *newItem);
    if (!newItem) exit(1);

    if (list->length >= list->capacity) {
        list->capacity *= 2;
        list->items = (Item**)realloc(list->items,   // BTW DONT DO THIS - SEE BELOW
            list->capacity * sizeof(Item*));
    }
    newItem->code = code;
    strcpy(newItem->string, string);
    list->items[list->length++] = newItem;
}
```

BTW: Always `realloc` to a tmp pointer like:

```
tmp = realloc(....);
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}
else
{
    list = tmp;
}
```

Further: In C it is normally not recommended to `cast` `malloc`/ `realloc` / `calloc`. It is also typical to use `sizeof *pointer` instead of  `sizeof(type)`

So instead of:

```
list->items = (Item**)realloc(list->items, list->capacity * sizeof(Item*));
```

you could do:

```
tmp = realloc(list->items, list->capacity * sizeof *tmp);
```

where `tmp` is the same type as `list->items`

Comment: Also drop a note about not casting the return of `realloc`. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) (the same applies to `realloc` and `calloc`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I already had a comment about that but now I have tried to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: How then would I go about freeing my temp?

Comment: @4386427 gotcha. I understood the original to be a copy/paste issue, but it is always good to make sure you are not repeating those practices in the answer. Good fix.

Comment: @compolo You never have to `free (temp)`. On successful `realloc`, `temp` is assigned to your original pointer and the block will be freed when you free the original pointer. On failure to `realloc`, `NULL` is returned and there is nothing allocated to `temp`, the original pointer is preserved and still points to the original block that existed prior to the `realloc` call (which is why you never `realloc` the original -- if it fails `NULL` is returned and you lose your reference to your original block of memory)

Comment: If it is practice not to cast realloc, malloc or calloc, what do I cast? I was taught to cast malloc especially.

Comment: Can you provide an example in the first code block of how you would implement this temp functionality?